# Multiline textbox rendering issue in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, wcf, textbox

I have developed a client page for wcf service. basically my page has one button and two textboxes one is for loading request xml from xml file, and another one is displaying response xml.
Problem is that after any error got from wcf service my request xml textbox ignores all xml nodes it just displays node values with even spaces.

this is working in one machine it is not working in another machine.
two machines are windows xp os, ie 7.

```
<TextBox ID="requesttextbox" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="470px"
                Height="300px" Wrap="false/>
```

button click code something like this

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.XmlResolver = null;
xmlDoc.LoadXml(requesttextbox.Text);
HttpWebRequest objHttpWebRequest = null;
HttpWebResponse objHttpWebResponse = null;

string strFinalRequestXML = xmlDoc.OuterXml;

objHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("RequestURL");
objHttpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
objHttpWebRequest.Accept = "xml";
objHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/xml; charset=utf-8";
objHttpWebRequest.Timeout = 300000;
objHttpWebRequest.ContentLength = strFinalRequestXML.Length;
System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter  (objHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
sw.Write(strFinalRequestXML);
sw.Close();

try
{
    objHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    Stream streamResponseText = objHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader srFinalResponseText = new StreamReader(streamResponseText, Encoding.UTF8);
    txtResponse.Text = string.Empty;

    // formattin xml string to as xml nodes to display in textbox
    System.Xml.Linq.XElement element = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(srFinalResponseText.ReadToEnd());
    txtResponse.Text = element.ToString();

    strStatusCode = objHttpWebResponse.StatusCode.GetHashCode().ToString();

}
catch (WebException objWebException)
{
}
```

*For example:*

request xml    <node>test</node> <node1>test;</node1>  inside request xml text box.
after error from wcf display as " test test".

i have no clue for this problem.

Comment: Some code might help with getting an answer.

Comment: Specifically, I meant the code calling the WCF service.

Comment: I thought you were using WCF? You shouldn't have to use HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse to call a WCF service. You should add the WCF to the Service References, which will auto-generate all the calling code.

Comment: issue is not with consuming wcf . only with text box rendering. i could not understand why should i change wcf counsuming code. how this code will access textboxt content? could you explain?

Comment: the issue with textbox not with wcf consuming . so why shuld i change the wcf consuming code?

Comment: Have you debugged this and looked at the text you're putting into the text box?

Comment: Also, get rid of that try/catch block. It's eating exceptions. I also don't see where your request text box is being changed after it is set. Finally, you need `using` blocks for your stream, streamreader and httpwebresponse.

Answer (score 1):

If you are truly using WCF, you shouldn't have to manually call the URL using HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse, nor should you have to parse the XML by hand. You should add the service to the Service References, see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx

If it is not WCF, but instead a regular SOAP web service, you can still add it as a Web Reference, see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx

Then you can write code that is a little easier:

```
using (var client = new MyService.MyServiceClient())
{
    string foo;
    foo = client.MyMethod();
}
```

As for the text display, there is nothing in your catch handler, so I'm not sure where the textbox would be getting any sort of value. You must be setting it somewhere outside the code snippet you have provided.

Comment: i could not understand why this will affect textbox text?

Comment: Yes, I realized I did not answer that part. I have updated my answer.

Comment: See my question is textbox issue. so you are answered for what i am not needed. i am not changing text box value while clicking on button.

Comment: txtResponse.Text = element.ToString(); is in the try part, so the text box either has a default value, or you are setting it somewhere else. No other code I can see is changing the text value.

Comment: i think you misunderstand. problem is with request xml text box,no t with response textbox.

Comment: I see no code setting the requesttextbox.Text property. Have you done a full search of your project?